Adding a sidebar that appears over all views
I want to add a sidebar to my application which would appear over all views that are handled by route_change() method and views_handler(). The implementation of those method is not relevant for my question so I am not going to copy them here. The problem im facing is as I understand it whenever I append to views list the sidebar would disappear and I would have to manually import it into all other page files. Is there a way to make the sidebar appear "on top" of all views no matter whats popped/appended?
I have not really tried anything yet. Im looking for any solution because I do not have any idea how to solve this problem.
I also don't want to make it as a page.appbar because that always appears "on top" of the page. I want it to be a sidebar.

Ok so basically, if I understand well, what you're trying to do here is put a sidebar on all the views of the application.
It's a little bit more difficult for me to help you because I don't have your code samples but the thing you have to do is create an App.vue where you put all your classes in there and import the sidebar only in the App.vue creating a layout for your application.
Maybe you'll have to implement it on each page as you said if your application is not a single page application though but if you really don't want to import each time, maybe you'll have to change the logic of your app.

As the tag says I am using a not so popular new Python framework called flet, which is a wrapper for Flutter. My app is a single page application which switches between views. I think currently the solution is to actually import for each view. Thanks for your answer.

One way to do it is to define your sidebar in a variable, then in the same method where you have defined the route_change, when you are going to append the view, you add a Row, where you will put the SideBar and the view, so the Sidebar will always appear in each selected view.
Example:
def route_change(e:ft.ViewPopEvent):        
        if page.route == "/":    
            page.views.clear()    
            page.views.append(ft.View(route='/', controls=[    
                ft.Row( controls=[    
                sidebar, # variable defined above    
                home_view() # variable defined view above    
            ],)    
            ],    
            vertical_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.START,    
            horizontal_alignment=ft.CrossAxisAlignment.START,    
            spacing=26    
            ))  

.
.
